Generalizing combinatory probability result
I have a deck of $50$ unique cards numbered from $1$ to $50$. I want to compute the probability to see card n°$1$, $2$ and $3$ appearing after drafting $5$ cards.
My reasoning is that if only drafting $3$ cards the solution is simply $p = \frac{3}{50} \cdot \frac{2}{49} \cdot \frac{1}{48}$. Now I guess that if I draft $2$ more cards the probability should be higher and I should get something like $p_1 = p \cdot {5 \choose 3} = \frac{1}{1960}$.
However when I try to generalize this solution I do not get convinced that my approach is correct. Let's say I now want to compute the probability of getting exactly $3$ cards between $1$ and $10$ (out of a $5$ cards draft, same deck) with what binomial should I multiply $p_2 = \frac{10}{50} \cdot \frac{9}{49} \cdot \frac{8}{48} \cdot \frac{40}{47} \cdot \frac{39}{46} \cdot {x \choose y}$ ? Obviously not $5 \choose 10$ since $10 > 5$.
I gave my reasonning, but I know it's likely to be incorrect. What would be the correct reasonning and what would be the probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$?

What is the number of all combinations to draft $5$ cards? It is $\binom{50}5$.
What is the number of all combinations where $3$ of the $5$ cards are fixed? We should choose other $2$ cards from the rest $47$ cards. There are $\binom{47}2$ to do that.
So the probability is equal to $$p_1=\frac{\binom{47}2}{\binom{50}5}=\frac{47\cdot46\cdot5!}{2\cdot50 \cdot49 \cdot48 \cdot47 \cdot46}= \frac{5\cdot 12\cdot2}{2\cdot10 \cdot5\cdot49 \cdot12\cdot4}= \frac1{49\cdot40}=\frac1{1960}.$$
Now let us calculate $p_2$. There are $\binom{50}5$ overall combinations. $3$ cards should be chosen from the first ten cards. There are $\binom{10}3$ ways to do that. The other $2$ cards are chosen from the rest $40$ cards. There are $\binom{40}2$ to do that. So the answer becomes
$$p_2=\frac{\binom{10}3\cdot\binom{40}2}{\binom{50}5} =\frac{2340}{52969}\approx0.044,$$
which is quite greater than $p_1$.

Thanks, but what about p2, where the 3 cards are not fixed, but are draft from another 10 cards subset ?

@Blackscholes I’ve edited my answer to include calculation of $p_2$.
